# How to use a member variable in multiple vue.js apps?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem with javascript and vue.js and hope, that somebody can help me.
In the html-file I have a canvas with id "canvas" and a button below with id "change" (if I click the button in the browser the key value should be changed).
In the javascript file I have a member variable "key" which I want to update in the "change"-vue app and also use in the "canvas"-vue app. 
The problem is, the key variable in the canvas-app doesn't take the value of the change-app.
How can I fix this?

```
let key = 0;

let changeApp = new Vue({

el:"#change",
    data:{
    },
    methods: {
        change: function () {
            this.key = 1;
    }
});

let canvasApp = new Vue({

el:"#canvas",
    data:{
    },
    methods: {
        useKey: function () {
            // use the updated key variable
            // this.key is always undefined
    }
});
```

(Btw If I define the key variable in the mounted-function (for instance with 2), I don't get undefined in the useKey-function, but the value 2).
I would be very thankful if somebody could help me. I hope, I have enough code provided and the question is clear, otherwise I can edit it.
Thanks!

Comment: key isn't on the instance, therefore vue has no idea what `this.key` is

Comment: Thanks! But how should I make it then?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [VueJS Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html). You're trying to pass data between multiple Vue instances so that couldn't work.

Make a **component** for your "change" div and another one for your "canvas". After that, you have to instanciate **one** Vue to a global div. Then, you will be able to pass data between your 2 components.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer! It looks a bit complicated, but I'll try it!